# PageTabViewStyle breaks NavigationView

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI view. When using the NavigationView inside the TabView the app works as expected.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                Text("A")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Nav A")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            NavigationView {
                Text("B")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Nav B")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        //.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)) // this line breaks the view
    }
}
```

As soon as I uncomment `.tabViewStyle(...)` the view does not work as expected. Any ideas why? The text is not visible anymore. The navigation does not seem to be correct either.

[image: Works fine without PageTabViewStyle]

[image: PageTabViewStyle breaks view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `NavigationView` outside the `TabView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                Text("A").tag(1)
                Text("B").tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .navigationTitle(selection == 1 ? "A" : "B")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. However this causes a different problem. I put NavigationView inside the TabView because I had a ScrollView inside the NavigationView. When I put the ScrollView inside the TabView now, the NavigationView does not respond to scroll anymore. (e.g. change title size). Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Finn You didn't mention the ScrollView in your question and this changes the whole context. Please create a new question and I'll try to help you there. And don't forget to describe your whole stack *accurately* (including the ScrollView and other possibly important elements).

Comment: Thank you. I thought the content of the TabView would be irrelevant, so I removed it. Here the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64118291/7179628).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `NavigationView` defaults to presenting as a primary/detail display.

You can force it to work like a normal navigation stack with the modifier `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

Here it is in your code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView {
            Text("A")
                .navigationBarTitle("Nav A")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        NavigationView {
            Text("B")
                .navigationBarTitle("Nav B")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)) 
}
```

}

Comment: This worked in my case